# Facebook oAuth extended permissions request

Tags: facebook, api, oauth

I like to request more (extended) permissions using FB API after user is already authenticated. Is it possible to send a valid access token or any other way to NOT login again using the OAuth Authentication?

Url looks like that: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri={callback_url}&scope=read_stream,publish_actions&display=popup&response_type=token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to send the user through the login dialog again.

Although, if the user is already logged into your app, he'll get a different (simpler) dialog only requesting additional permissions. This is handle by Facebook automatically.

Comment: Thanks. But that seems not to work using the WebAuthenticationBroker for the OAuth Request (WinJS). Is it based on Cookies, or where does the "user is already logged in" information come from?